# SVN externals global for all team member

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, subclipse

I'm using TortoiseSVN and Subclipse.

I have following Project structure in one SVN repository

```
 /prj1
    -file.py
 /prj2
    -file2.py
    -file3.py
```

Now I want to use the file3.py in both projects.

I was able to do that localy for me with svn:externals via Subclipse

But that is just visible for me and not for all Team members.

How is it possible to make it global?

Comment: What are the versions of `svn` libraries in TortoiseSVN and Subclipse? Old versions support externals only on folders, but not on files.

Comment: @Dialecticus Subversion 1.8.10

Comment: So the file is not there, but is the `externals` property there?

Comment: @Dialecticus If you mean, that the property should be visible for all, than the answer is no.

Comment: Are the paths to the repositories identical? Maybe you are looking at different branches. Also (stupid question) have you in fact committed the change, and tried to update it on the other machine?

Comment: @Dialecticus Ok stupid question results in a stupid answer "NO". Didn't commit the changes :( Shame on me.  If you would be so frankly to write an Answer so I can acept it . Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some reasons why a commit of a single `external` file is not visible in another working copy:

- Maybe the other svn client does not support `external` properties for single files. Client must be at least version 1.6 (pretty old).
- You may have committed a change to one branch, but expecting it in another.
- Maybe the change was not committed in the first place.
- Maybe the change was committed, but the other working copy is not yet updated.